# Scala : How to process objects in a list

Tags: scala

I am using spark and scala on jdk1.8.I am new to Scala.
I am collecting a list of objects as :

```
val externalEntities  =  getExternalGenericExtractFiles()
```

That functions returns (**from Java world**):

```
public List<GenericExtractExternalEntity> getExternalGenericExtractFiles()
{
    return externalGenericExtractFiles;
}
```

Now I am trying :

```
externalEntities.forEach( externalEntity =>
  sqlContext.read.format(externalEntity.getExtractfileType)
    .option("compression", externalEntity.getCompressionCodec)
    .option("delimiter", externalEntity.getExtractDelimiter)
    .option("header", if (externalEntity.getHasHeader.toUpperCase == "Y") "true" else "false")
    .load(externalEntity.getFilePath)
    .createOrReplaceTempView(externalEntity.getExtractName)
)
```

and getting error :

```
error: missing parameter type
[ERROR]     externalEntities.forEach(externalEntity =>
```

**I thought Scala is capable of inferring type. What am I missing here?**

If I try just one object from the list, it seems fine like if I do

```
val externalEntity=  getExternalGenericExtractFiles().get(0)

sqlContext.read.format(externalEntity.getExtractfileType)
    .option("compression", externalEntity.getCompressionCodec)
    .option("delimiter", externalEntity.getExtractDelimiter)
    .option("header", if (externalEntity.getHasHeader.toUpperCase == "Y") "true" else "false")
    .load(externalEntity.getFilePath)
    .createOrReplaceTempView(externalEntity.getExtractName)
```

May I get any insight on what is happening and/or how to resolve?
Thanks in advance

Comment: That `forEach` you are using is actually a java `forEach`, not the scala one.

Comment: I tried thus in a **RELP** _(version 2.12.8)_, and worked. `val l: java.util.List[Integer] = new java.util.LinkedList[java.lang.Integer]()`, `l.add(0)`, `l.forEach(x => println(x + 1))`. Can you provide a **MCVE** we could test?

Comment: Never mind, I tried the same in a **RELP** _(version 2.11.12)_ and it has the same error. Probably it is because scala 2.12 was the first version of Scala to require a minimum version of JDK 8, which allowed them to improve compatibility with Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I had a typo ("forEach"instead of "foreach") and needed little extra:**

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val externalEntities:List[GenericExtractExternalEntity]  =  
                  getExternalGenericExtractFiles()
                  .asScala
                  .iterator
                  .toList

externalEntities.foreach ( externalEntity =>
  sqlContext.read.format(externalEntity.getExtractfileType)
    .option("compression", externalEntity.getCompressionCodec)
    .option("delimiter", externalEntity.getExtractDelimiter)
    .option("header", if (externalEntity.getHasHeader.toUpperCase == "Y") "true" else "false")
    .load(externalEntity.getFilePath)
    .createOrReplaceTempView(externalEntity.getExtractName)
)
```

**And it worked.**

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are not using Scala 2.12. Using Scala lambdas with Java functional interfaces requires Scala 2.12. That error message often occurs when you pass a lambda where one is not expected, which would happen in this case in 2.11. Upgrade your Scala version, or [convert the list to a Scala list](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html).